# trying to server the file with a link but it is prompting me to download on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I had a link which is called during the page load like:

```
<a href="#modify()#">Download</a>
```

the above link appears in the modal window when a link is clicked from the parent window. i want to trigger the function when i click the download button but instead it is downloading on the page load, how can i stop it from happening on page load and only server with when the download is clicked

trying something like this but it is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).on('click','.download',function() {
                    location.href = '<cfoutput>#modify()#</cfoutput>'
                };
            </script>
            <a href="##" class="download">Download</a>
```

Comment: Is any of this in a `<cfoutput>` ?

Comment: u mean the item being served, if that the modify function is serving the file

Comment: can i do something like serve the file on fly by storing it temp location when the button is clicked, because on page load

Comment: The code for the modify() function might shed some light on this matter.

Comment: its using cfcontent to serve the file as attachment and after the cfcontent, i am just doing writeoutput

Comment: cfcontent( reset=true, type="application/unknown" );
   cfheader( name="Content-Disposition", value="attachment; filename=p.rtf");
   writeoutput(#results#);

Comment: Looks to me like the download link should go to a download.cfm page that will do the download. It looks like you might be confusing server side code with front-end code (javascript), which only runs in the browser. You're also using jquery, so you're going to want to get a good handle on the jquery library.

Answer (score 1):

You may have overcomplicated something that should be simple.  I suggest

- Forget the function.  Put the download code into a simple .cfm page.
- Forget about the writeoutput after the cfheader and cfcontent commands.  It won't execute.
- have your anchor tag point to that page.  Add url variables and a target attribute if appropriate.

The result will look something like this:

```
<a href="PageWithDownloadCode.cfm?userid=2" target="_blank">
```

Comment: yes,, Thanks that was my initial approach, but what i am trying now is the function writes the file in a location, and providesd a link to download, i think there is something in cfcontent or cfheader that file can be deleted , like this 

<cffile action="write" file="somelocation">

Comment: then,, return < ahref="myurl.pdf">myurl.pdf</a> - after this is clicked, i want the file should be deleted from disk immediately

Comment: You are correct that `cfcontent` has an attribute that enables you to delete the file immediately.  I just looked it up.  However, you still don't need a function.